# Can we do predictions for sub-classes i.e. class within class?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I need to classify an object into multiple classes. Normally we are familiar with multi-class classification with a single hierarchy, but in my case I have two levels of hierarchy. See the below images to get a clear picture of what I am talking about. so that if I want to classify an image, it should give me all three classes: one is the main class and two subclasses. For example, Class-1-1-1, or Class-1-2-3.

[image: Hierarchy of class]

Solution for any framework will work either Tensorflow or PyTorch. Thank You.

Comment: Look into multi-label classification, or you could run two submodels together, one doing binary classification on classes `0` and `1`, and the other multi-class on classes `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Comment: yes, Djinn this would be better idea to go  with really helped me a lot . But to be  more precise do you mean having  two or three models working in sequence one after the other?

Comment: If you go the second route, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your hierarchy tree, wouldn't it be ok for you to do multi-class classification on the leaves (the final classes), then check what are the parent classes in the tree, for a given prediction ?